# Angular Module with Router overrides default routes

Tags: angular, angular15

I am using my `TestModule` in main `routing.module.ts` which is available on the path `/test`

```
   {
      path: "test",
      loadChildren: () => import('../pages/test.module').then(m => m.TestModule),
   },
```

And here is `test.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: TestComponent,
    },
];
@NgModule({
    declarations: [TestComponent, Test2Component],
    imports: [
        OtherModules,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes), 
    ],
    exports: [Test2Component],
})
export class TestModule {}
```

Then I import `TestModule` to use one of the components in another module `NavBarModule` which is available everywhere. And as a result, my default routes are overridden, and my `TestComponent` is available in those routes where it should not be available.
Angular v15. How can I fix this?